# TouchImageView by MikeOrtiz used to edit original img

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap

I am using TouchImageView by MikeOrtiz (https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView).
I want to add folowing functionality: 
In *TIV*(TouchImageView) will be loaden preview of an image saved on SDCard, user will scroll and zoom. Then I need to crop original image according to what is visible in *TIV*.
Is there any way to get coordinates of visible bitmap? 
Thanks

Comment: I am working on this as well but have yet so far not found any solution. Have you?

Answer (score 2):

it's pretty simple,  TouchImageView is a subclass of ImageView, so you should search how to get ImageView visible area.  Here there are some code to do that:

```
TouchImageView img = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewZoom);
Bitmap bitmap = null;
img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.getDrawingCache());   // get visible image
img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

bitmap variable has visible imageview, then you can save it to disk, show in another imageview or whathever you need.  Hope it helps you